From exponent of sum to product of exponents
Good day
I have an expression
Exp[m I (a (Exp[-I x] + Exp[+I x]) + b (Exp[-3 I x] + Exp[+3 I x]))]

I want to convince Mathematica to expand the exponent,
Exp[m I a Exp[-I x] + m I a Exp[+I x] + m I b Exp[-3 I x] + 
  m I b Exp[+3 I x]]

then apply ExpToTrig only to the exponent
Exp[2 a m I Cos[x] + 2 b m I Cos[3 x]]

then convert the exponent of a sum to a product of exponents
Exp[2 a m I Cos[x]] Exp[2 b m I Cos[3 x]]

For info: my final goal is to apply the Jacobi-Anger expansion
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion
but that is not the subject of my question.
All my variables are real.
For some reason I cannot convince Mathematica to take these steps.
I already tried Expand, FullSimplify (assuming all variables are real), Simplify, ExpToTrig, Refine assuming all variables are real.
I also tried first taking the Log of my expression, then expanding.
Note that I cannot even obtain the expansion of the exponent.
Any help is appreciated.
Boudewijn Verhaar

Clear["Global`*"];
expr = Exp[
  m I (a (Exp[-I x] + Exp[+I x]) + b (Exp[-3 I x] + Exp[+3 I x]))]

expr0 = expr /. Power[E, a__] :> Power[E, Expand[a]]

expr1 = expr /. Power[E, a__] :> Power[E, ExpToTrig[a]]


$e^{2 i a m \cos (x)+2 i b m \cos (3 x)}$

expr1 //. E^(a_ + b_) :> Defer[E^a E^b ]


$e^{2 i a m \cos (x)} e^{2 i b m \cos (3 x)}$

% /. Defer :> Identity


It worked, thank you!

I am glad to know that it worked. You can click the greyed out tick mark next to the answer to accept it. Thanks.

Ah, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks again! I'll do that retrospectively for answers to other questions.
